# Loading events in ionic2-calendar from firestore async issue?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an app with ionic6 and just starting with it.
I want to display in a calendar events that I stored in firestore.
I'm using angular and ionic2-calendar.

I'm really starting with Angular and js so be kind :)

With the following code, the items are loaded after the page to be initialized :

```
resa-calend-view.page.ts:29 constructor
resa-calend-view.page.ts:33 Begin ngonInit
resa-calend-view.page.ts:42 onInit 0 items
```

I tried a lot of configurations with async/await (you can see some traces of them :( but without any success.
My events are not loaded when the page loads.

Do you have any clue or something that I have done wrong ?

Perhaps I'm mistaken from the beginning.
Here are my files:

### resa-calend-view.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, LOCALE_ID, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CrudService } from '../../services/crud.service';
import { AlertController, IonDatetime, ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CalendarComponent } from "ionic2-calendar";
import { start } from 'repl';
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-resa-calend-view',
  templateUrl: './resa-calend-view.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./resa-calend-view.page.scss'],
})
export class ResaCalendViewPage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(CalendarComponent) myCal: CalendarComponent | undefined;
  eventSource: any[] = [];
  viewTitle: string = "";

  calendar = {
    mode: 'month',
    currentDate: new Date(),
  };

  selectedDate: Date = new Date();  
  items: any[] = [];
  //@ViewChild(CalendarComponent) myCal: CalendarComponent;
  constructor(public db: CrudService, private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    @Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string,
    private modalCtrl: ModalController) { console.log("constructor");
     }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Begin ngonInit");
    this.db.ResaRef.snapshotChanges()
        .subscribe(resas => {
          resas.forEach(resa => {
            console.log('Item: ' + resa.payload.doc.data());  
            this.items.push(resa.payload.doc.data())
          });
    });
    this.initResas(); 
    console.log("onInit " + this.items.length + " items")
  }
initResas(){
  var startTime;
  var endTime;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i += 1) {
    console.log("init " + this.items[i].nom);
    //start date
    startTime = new Date(
      Date.UTC(
        this.items[i].date_arrivee.substring(0, 4),
        this.items[i].date_arrivee.substring(5, 7),
        this.items[i].date_arrivee.substring(8, 10)
      )); 
    endTime = new Date(
      Date.UTC(
        this.items[i].date_depart.substring(0, 4),
        this.items[i].date_depart.substring(5, 7),
        this.items[i].date_depart.substring(8, 10)
      ));
      this.eventSource.push({
        title: this.items[i].nom,
        startTime: startTime,
        endTime: endTime,
        allDay: true,
      });
  }
  this.myCal?.loadEvents();
}
// Change current month/week/day
next() {
  this.myCal?.slideNext();
}

back() {
  this.myCal?.slidePrev();
}
 
    
}
```

### resa-calend-view.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Calendar
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button>
        <ion-icon name="add" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="calendar.mode">
    <ion-segment-button value="month">
      <ion-label>Month</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="week">
      <ion-label>Week</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size="6">
      <ion-button (click)="createRandomEvents()" expand="block" fill="outline">
        Add random events
      </ion-button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="6">
      <ion-button (click)="removeEvents()" expand="block" fill="outline">
        Remove all events
      </ion-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row>
    <!-- Move back one screen of the slides -->
    <ion-col size="2">
      <ion-button (click)=back() fill="clear">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-back" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col size="8" class="ion-text-center">
      <h2>{{ viewTitle }}</h2>
    </ion-col>

    <!-- Move forward one screen of the slides -->
    <ion-col size="2">
      <ion-button (click)=next() fill="clear">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-forward" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <calendar
    [eventSource]="eventSource"
    [calendarMode]="calendar.mode"
    [currentDate]="calendar.currentDate"
    startHour="6"
    endHour="20"
    step="30"
    startingDayWeek="1"
  >
  </calendar>

</ion-content>
```

### crud.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";



export class Resa {
  nom: string ="";
  prenom: string = "";
  date_arrivee: string=""
  date_depart: string=""
  mail: string=""
  prix: string=""
  source: string=""
  telephone: string=""
  funpass: string=""
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CrudService {
  items:any[] = []
  ResaRef!: AngularFirestoreCollection<Resa>;
  myResa:Resa = new Resa();
  resas!: Promise<any[]>;
  constructor(
    private db: AngularFirestore,
    private router: Router
  ) { 
    console.log("Constructor service")
    this.ResaRef = db.collection("reservations");
  }

  getAll(): AngularFirestoreCollection<Resa> {
    return this.ResaRef;
  }
  getItems(){
    console.log("Getting Items")
    this.items = []
    let test = this.db.collection('reservations').get().subscribe((ss) => {
      ss.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                        this.items.push(doc.data());
                        console.log("browsing results" + doc.id)
                      });
    });

    return this.items
  }
  async getResas(){
    console.log("Getting Items async")
    this.items = []
    let test = this.db.collection('reservations').get().subscribe((ss) => {
      ss.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        this.items.push(doc.data());
        console.log("browsing results" + doc.id);
      });
    });
  
    return this.items
  }

  async saveResa(resa:any){
    let date_a = new Date(resa.date_a_str)
    let date_a_str = date_a.getDate() +"-"+date_a.getMonth() + "-" + date_a.getFullYear()
    const idResa= resa.nom +"-" + resa.date_arrivee
    console.log("Saving Resa" + idResa)
    const res = await this.db.collection('reservations').doc(idResa).set(resa);
    
    return this.items
  }

  getTasks() {
    return this.db.collection('tasks').snapshotChanges();
  }
  

  delete(id: string) {
    this.db.doc('tasks/' + id).delete();
  }

}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You should be using ionic's calendar component instead. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime. with that being said. you made have placed your code in the wrong lifecycle method. Try using ngAfterContentinit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it with ngAfterContentinit.
DataTime seems to be an input calendar, I would like to display existing events in a calendar, I don't want the user to be able to pick dates. I'm not sure DateTime is doing that.